# Update data table in dialog from another dialog in PrimeFaces 5

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to JSF/PrimeFaces and am trying to update a DataTable(SearchResultsTable) in my Dialog(SearchResultsDlg)from another Dialog(SearchDlg)  I tried putting my List of Objects on the the `FacesContext` and I tried to make it the return type but Dialog(SearchResultsDlg) keeps popping up empty.  No errors on the java side and I know I'm returning a List of type Object from my query.  Here is snippits of code in the order in which they execute.  Any ideas would be great!

Search.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:dialog id="SearchDlg"
              widgetVar="SearchDialog"
              modal="true"
              resizable="false"
              appendTo="@(body)" header="#{bundle.Search}">

        <h:form id="SearchForm" >
            <h:panelGroup id="SearchDisplay">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel  id="SearchLabel" value="What" />
                    <p:inputText    id="SearchText" value="#{offerController.searchText}" size="40"/>

                    <p:outputLabel  id="ZipCodeLabel" value="Where" />
                    <p:inputText    id="postalcode" value="#{offerController.postalCode}" size="12"/>
                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton id="Search"
                                 value="Search"
                                 actionListener="#{offerController.search}"
                                 onclick="handleSubmit(args, 'SearchDialog')" />
                <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Cancel}"  onclick="SearchDialog.hide()"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

OfferController.java

```
public List<Offer> search() {

    List<Offer> offers = null;
    try {
        offers = getFacade().search(PostalCode, Distance, Category, SubCategory, SearchText, SearchType);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("offer", offers);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("SearchResult");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("SearchResultsTable");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return offers;
}
```

SearchResults.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:dialog id="SearchResultsDlg"
              widgetVar="SearchResultsDialog"
              modal="true"
              resizable="false"
              appendTo="@(body)"
              header="#{bundle.Login}" >

        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfferTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:form id="SearchResultsForm">
                <p:panel header="#{bundle.ListOfferTitle}">
                    <p:dataTable id="SearchResultsTable" value="#{offerController.search}" var="offer"
                                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{offerController.selected}"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 rowKey="#{offer.name}"
                                 rows="10"
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50">

                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
                        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfferTitle_sellerUserID}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{offer.sellerUserID}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfferTitle_name}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{offer.name}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: You should try something simpler, like updating a single String value from one dialog to another. If you have problem, your StackOverflow question will be nice and short.

Comment: It also looks like you're misunderstanding how `update` works: it doesn't make sense to target buttons.

Comment: David Thanks for the comments.  I will look into working with a string but I was hoping to get some help with the DataTable.  The update="createButton is auto generated by Netbeans/Primefaces and that piece works fine.

Comment: What you're trying to do is practically no different whether you're using a String or a datatable. If you can do one, you should be able to do the other. The only thing throwing a datatable into the mix achieves is added complexity, which you really don't need if you're just getting into JSF.

Comment: Agree.  So your suggesting I use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(); ?

Comment: I think that _could_ work, but you'll have an easier time using higher-level JSF tools, like backing-bean `ViewScoped` or `SessionScoped`, @user4852215. You shouldn't need to access low-level stuff too often when using JSF. If the dialogs are on totally different Facelets pages, you'll need `SessionScoped` or similar (`ViewScoped` is for post backs).

Comment: This issue is resolved.  It was primarily an issue with to many <ui:define name="body"> tags in a <ui:composition> page.  I did endup modifing some methods to make it work better.  Here they are. FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("search", search);   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('SearchDialog').hide()");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('SearchResultsDialog').show()");

Answer (score 0):

Use `selector` for `update`:

```
p:dataTable id="SearchResultsTable" styleClass="for-update"
```

and `button` or `ajax`:

```
p:commandButton id="Search" update="@(.for-update)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the component you want to update from the component that tirggers the update action. For example if I want to update "dataTable1" contained in "dialog1" from "button2" contained in "dialog2":

```
<p:dialog id="dialog1" ... >
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable1"...>
            ...
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
<p:dialog id="dialog2" ... >
    <h:form id="form2">
        <p:commandButton
            process="@form" update=":form1:dataTable1" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```